# Test if class's generic parameter is itself the same class with its own generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I'm not sure I've phrased the title correctly, but hopefully my pseudo code is nearly self explanatory. I don't know how to test if a `SomeType` object is an instance of MyClass (or a descendent). How could this be achieved?

```
public class MyClass<SomeType>
{
    //...
    public void a(SomeType st)
    {
        if (SomeType extendsOrIs MyClass<?>) // Need help with this line
        {
            MyClass<?> mc = (MyClass<?>) st;
            mc.b();
        }
    }
    public void b()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

One solution I've found is to do this, but it's possible the object is null, in which case I'd still like to know if `SomeType` is equivalent to `MyClass<?>` for the sake of calling a method for future objects:

```
    public void a(SomeType st)
    {
        if (st instanceof MyClass<?>)
        {
            MyClass<?> mc = (MyClass<?>) st;
            mc.b();
        }
    }
```

Comment: but it's possible the object is null?? What you mean

Comment: `null` has no class - so it's not possible to check what the class of a `null` value is because it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of null is not an instance of any class.You can create a final method in `MyClass` such as :-

```
public class MyClass<SomeType>
{
    //...
    public void a(SomeType st)
    {
        if (SomeType extendsOrIs MyClass<?>) // Need help with this line
        {
            MyClass<?> mc = (MyClass<?>) st;
            mc.b();
        }
    }
   public final boolean isSubClass()
   {    
     if(this.getClass()!=MyClass.class){
     return true;
     }
    return false;
   }

public void a(SomeType st)
    {
        if (st instanceof MyClass<?>)
        {
            MyClass<?> mc = (MyClass<?>) st;
            mc.isSubClass();
        }
    }
```